# js background change depends on weather condition (code not working)

Tags: javascript, openweathermap

condition is not working though the "Categoryvalue" has data in it. I'm just new in JS.
is my approach wrong? how to change the background that depends on weather conditions?

```
var button = document.querySelector('.button')
var inputValue = document.querySelector('.inputValue')
var name1 = document.querySelector('.name1');
var desc = document.querySelector('.desc');
var temp = document.querySelector('.temp'); 
var category = document.querySelector('.category'); 

button.addEventListener('click',function(){
    fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+inputValue.value+'&appid=<removed>')
    .then(response => response.json()) 
    // .then(data => console.log(data))
    .then(data => {
        var nameValue = data['name'];
        var categoryValue =data['weather'][0]['main'];
        var tempValue = data['main']['temp'];
        var descValue = data['weather'][0]['description'];
        var tofloat = Math.abs(tempValue - 273.15);
        var tempCelcius= parseFloat(tofloat).toFixed(2);

        name1.innerHTML = nameValue;
        category.innerHTML = categoryValue;
        temp.innerHTML = tempCelcius;
        desc.innerHTML = descValue;

        if(categoryValue == 'Clear'){
            document.body.style.backgroundImage =url('../pictures/clear.jpg');
        }else if(categoryValue == 'Clouds'){
            document.body.style.backgroundImage =url('../pictures/clouds.jpg');
        }else if(categoryValue == 'Rain'){
            document.body.style.backgroundImage = url("../pictures/rain.jpg");
        }
    })
.catch(err => alert("Wrong City Name!"))
})
```

Comment: where is the problem? the way you change the background, or the way that you get the information about if its raining?

Comment: the way i change the background image. in if else condition

Comment: add `console.log(categoryValue)`

Comment: nvm, i know what the problem, i will write it in a moment

Comment: seems like 2 peoples already answered, so i wont write

Comment: error in your console should be clear as day what the issue is.

Comment: It would make more sense to toggle a class and have style sheet rules.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot surround `url()` with qoutes:

```
    if(categoryValue == 'Clear'){
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('../pictures/clear.jpg')";
    }else if(categoryValue == 'Clouds'){
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('../pictures/clouds.jpg')";
    }else if(categoryValue == 'Rain'){
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('../pictures/rain.jpg')";
    }
```

But I'd recommend avoid using inline style and change it via CSS with something like this:

```js
var button = document.querySelector('.button')
var inputValue = document.querySelector('.inputValue')
var name1 = document.querySelector('.name1');
var desc = document.querySelector('.desc');
var temp = document.querySelector('.temp'); 
var category = document.querySelector('.category'); 

button.addEventListener('click',function(){
    fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+inputValue.value+'&appid=' +document.getElementById("api").value)
    .then(response => response.json()) 
    // .then(data => console.log(data))
    .then(data => {
        var nameValue = data['name'];
        var categoryValue =data['weather'][0]['main'];
        var tempValue = data['main']['temp'];
        var descValue = data['weather'][0]['description'];
        var tofloat = Math.abs(tempValue - 273.15);
        var tempCelcius= parseFloat(tofloat).toFixed(2);

        name1.innerHTML = nameValue;
        category.innerHTML = categoryValue;
        temp.innerHTML = tempCelcius;
        desc.innerHTML = descValue;

        document.body.setAttribute("category", categoryValue);
/*
        if(categoryValue == 'Clear'){
            document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('../pictures/clear.jpg')";
        }else if(categoryValue == 'Clouds'){
            document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('../pictures/clouds.jpg')";
        }else if(categoryValue == 'Rain'){
            document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('../pictures/rain.jpg')";
        }
*/
     })
.catch(err => alert("Wrong City Name!"))
})
```

```css
body[category="Clear"]
{
  background-image: url('../pictures/clear.jpg');
  background-color: lightblue;
}
body[category="Clouds"]
{
  background-image: url('../pictures/clouds.jpg');
  background-color: silver;
}
body[category="Rain"]
{
  background-image: url('../pictures/rain.jpg');
  background-color: dimgray;
}


body[category="Clear"] .category
{
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
body[category="Clouds"] .category
{
  background-color: dimgray;
  color: white;
}
body[category="Rain"] .category
{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div><a href="https://openweathermap.org/api" target="_blank">API ID</a>: <input id="api"></div>
City: <input class="inputValue">
<button class="button">Submit</button>

<div class="name1"></div>
<div class="desc"></div>
<div class="temp"></div>
<div class="category"></div>
```

With this method not only you have more control about style, but also if there is a "unknown" category, it will automatically fall back to default style.

Comment: thank you, masters, that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

When changing the body element background image, you must set the value for `document.body.style.backgroundImage` as a string. Otherwise, you are calling a function with the `url` name, which doesn't exists, so an error is thrown. Therefore, your condition code would be this way:

```
    if (categoryValue == 'Clear') {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url("../pictures/clear.jpg")';
    } else if(categoryValue == 'Clouds'){
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url("../pictures/clouds.jpg")';
    } else if(categoryValue == 'Rain'){
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url("../pictures/rain.jpg")';
    }
```